# Selenium IDE Automation - find Element and click but nothing happens

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I wrote a short automation for website:
https://www.sapfioritrial.com/
after clicking in the first page successfully on a link and navigating to the next page, i find an object there successfully but the click doesn't effect and nothing happens.
[image: Selenium IDE test flow]

I am trying to click on "My Inbox"

Comment: Which command is not working? Can you try changing the Target(If the button have multiple ways of finding lement, Target will have many values).

Comment: Try to click child element, find it by xpath: `//div[@id='__tile2']//h3`

Comment: @kotoj Tried, not working

Comment: @Siva to click on "My Inbox" div (button)

Comment: @YuvalLevy Im Sorrry, im not able to see in "My Inbox" when i launch the url you have given. May be i need to Login. Try watAndClick(), if it doesnt work try running the code, reducing the speed of execution. There could be some synchronization issues also.

Comment: @Siva you need to lunch the website, then click on "see it in action" and there...

Comment: @Yuval Levy you are right, I reproduced it, also `click` do nothing. Change command to `clickAt`, it works for me

Comment: @YuvalLevy, try `clickAt` as suggested by kotoj. It will work, i gave explanation in his comments on why `click` did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why, but command `clickAt` works in this case.

[image]

Comment: The Reason is `click` only works for a link, button, checkbox or radio button. Where as `clickAt` will click on x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) returned by the locator

Comment: Understand. But in selenium IDE description for `clickAt` is the same:) "Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or radio button."

Comment: You are right, it will also click taking reference position as well